# telnetlib read_until() function confusion

Tags: python, telnetlib

I am trying to automate some telnet actions with python3. So I started to use the build in telnetlib (not pexpect).

Actually everything works so far but I do not understand completly how read_until works - actually the documentation says that you can set a timeout and if the search string is not found the timeout sends back a empty byte value or or if there is another value thats the one which can be stored as a return value!

Does that make sense ?!

If I wanna read_until a certain value - how do I find out that this value was really the one the function read. Also I couldn't find out how to check if the timeout was hit.

My workaround for now is:

```
output = telnet.read_until(str.encode(hostname), 3)
if re.search(hostname, bytes.decode(output), re.IGNORECASE):
   #do something when the output matches the searchstring
else:
   #stop the function
```

but that doesn't make any sense for me, so perhaps you now a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your hostname is `example.com`, read_until will return something like `weijwrgnerg hgqwv  blather example.com`. Except if it hasn't found the hostname after three seconds, it will just spit out whatever it's got by then: `weijwrgnerg hg`.

So I think you're doing it almost right. You probably want to `re.escape` your hostname, otherwise it will interpret it as a regex. Alternatively, you could just use Python's `.endswith()`. And you can do `output.decode()` to get a string (rather than `bytes.decode(output)`).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!
I do unterstand now how read_until works - stil it does not make that much sense why it was implemented like that, but ok!
<br />
I rewrote my implementation now to:

output = telnet.read_until(hostname.encode(), 3)
if re.search(re.escape(hostname), output.decode(), flags=re.IGNORECASE):

another question raised - isn't it necessary to define hostname.encode('ascii') or something like that ???

like
telnet.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

Comment: @Herbert: You're welcome. If you use encode or decode without specifying a codec, it will use the system default (`sys.getdefaultencoding()`), which is ascii in Python 2 and utf-8 in Python 3.

Comment: fine, I am using python 3 so it is UFT-8 which I wanna support - hopefully the telnet implementation do support UTF-8 on the different clients as well :)

Comment: @Herbert: Telnet itself should let you send any series of bytes. The important thing is to match what the other end is using: sending non-ascii characters will only work if the server you're talking to supports it as well.